# Cannot connect to MySQL Server on RHEL 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, redhat

I have a standard MySQL Server running on Red hat 5.7.  I have edited /etc/my.cnf to specify the bind address as my server's public IP address.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks    ;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

bind-address=171.67.88.25
port=3306
```

And I have also restarted my firewall

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

The network administrator has already opened port 3306 for this box.
When connecting from a remote computer (running Ubuntu 10.10, server is running RHEL 5.7), I issue

```
mysql -u jeffrey -p --host=171.67.88.25 --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

but receive a ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '171.67.88.25' (113).

I've noticed that the socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock is blank.  Should this be the case?

### **UPDATE**

The result of `netstat -an | grep 3306`

```
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Result of `sudo netstat -tulpen`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2208              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7602       3168/hpiod          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27         7827       3298/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          5110       2802/portmap        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8431       3326/rserver        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:915                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          5312       2853/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7655       3188/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7688       3199/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          8025       3362/sendmail: acce 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2207              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          7620       3173/python         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:909                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          5300       2853/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:912                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          5309       2853/rpc.statd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               0          4800       2598/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36177               0.0.0.0:*                               70         8314       3476/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353                0.0.0.0:*                               70         8313       3476/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          5109       2802/portmap        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          7691       3199/cupsd
```

Result of `sudo /sbin/iptables -L -v -n`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
6373 2110K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1241 packets, 932K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
572  861K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
1    28 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
46  6457 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
782  157K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
2   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:23 
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
4970 1086K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Result of `nmap -P0 -p3306 171.67.88.25`

```
Host is up (0.027s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

**Solution**

When everything else fails, go GUI!  `system-config-securitylevel` and add port 3306.  All done!

Comment: What do you see when you run `netstat -an | grep 3306`? Is the **LISTEN** there?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the Bind, restarting the MySQL server, then connecting again?

Comment: Well, I just did an Nmap of the IP address you're connecting to. It doesn't look like the port for mysql is open (which could be either from your machine's firewall rules, or the port not being forwarded on the router).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is some extra firewall for our University that only allows connections from within the campus.  The network admins said they have opened port 3306 for this server.  Can you show me how to use the Nmap command, so I can test it from within our campus network?

Comment: sure! You may have to install nmap, but the command is 'nmap -P0 -p3306 <ip address>'.

Comment: Host is up (0.027s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds

Comment: yup, that port is definitely not open. I think there may have been something wrong with your initial port-opening rule (since I can't see it on your iptables dump). Can you issue 'iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT', then reissuing the nmap scan?

Comment: Interesting, I issued the iptables command but nothing changed - still says "filtered"...

Comment: If all else fails, go graphical. Try enabling the port via 'system-config-securitylevel'. If an nmap doesn't show it open after that, then something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also unable to telnet to the machine port:

```
[bart@uk ~]$ telnet 171.67.88.25 3306
Trying 171.67.88.25...
```

Please post the output for `iptables -L -v -n` and `netstat -tulpen`. Can you try turning your firewall off?

Comment: Updated original post to include the output of netstat -tulpen.  When I do iptables -L v -n I get an error iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. Can you try again?

Comment: Original post updated.  I'm not sure how to read the output but shouldn't there be an entry for mysql Chain-RH Firewall Input?

Answer (score 0):

could you try add the block under [mysqld]

```
 [mysqld]
 bind-address=171.67.88.25
 port=3306
```

Comment: I moved that block under the [mysqld] section with no effect.  I also commented out bind-address with no change either :(

Answer (score 0):

Check selinux status (/etc/selinux/config).
To disable selinux set SELINUX=disabled and reboot the server.

Comment: I tried this with SELINUX=disabled and SELINUX=permissive, but neither worked :(

Comment: NEVER disable. set to permissive.